# AngularJs Form validation when select radio buttons

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am learner in angularJS and in my form i have name and email fields and one radio group for gender selection and my requirement is when i select male then name field is required and if i select female then email field is required

I have tried below code but its not working can some one help me please

### code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal alert alert-warning" name="empList" id="empForm" ng-submit="insertInfo(empInfo)">

    <h3 class="text-center">Insert Employee Details Into Database</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Employee Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="emp_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Employee Name" ng-model="empInfo.name"
            required="gender.value=='male'" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="text-danger" ng-show="empList.emp_name.$invalid">Name field is Empty!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="emp_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Employee Email Address" ng-model="empInfo.email"
            autofocus  required="gender.value=='female'"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="text-danger" ng-show="empList.emp_email.$invalid>Invalid Email!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
        <label for="" class="radio-inline gender">
            <input type="radio" name="emp_gender" value="male" ng-model="empInfo.gender" #gender="ng-model">Male
        </label>
        <label for="" class="radio-inline gender">
            <input type="radio" name="emp_gender" value="female" ng-model="empInfo.gender" #gender="ng-model">Female
        </label>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: 1. show log of the gender object when a gender is selected. 
2. try changing "required" to "ng-required".

Comment: user = {
  "name": "zf",
  "gender": "male"
}

Comment: please suggest me with code

Comment: try changing required="gender.value=='male'" to ng-required="gender.value=='male'"

Comment: no its not working

Comment: No one have idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with that validation: 
HTML :

```
      <form class="form-horizontal alert alert-warning" name="empList" id="empForm" ng-submit="insertInfo(empInfo)">

    <h3 class="text-center">Insert Employee Details Into Database</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name" ng-show="empInfo.gender != male_value">Employee Name is required</label>
        <input type="text" name="emp_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Employee Name" ng-model="empInfo.name"
            required="gender.value=='male'" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="text-danger" ng-show="empList.emp_name.$invalid">Name field is Empty!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email" ng-show="empInfo.gender == male_value">Email Address is rquired</label>
        <input type="email" name="emp_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Employee Email Address" ng-model="empInfo.email"
              required="gender.value=='female'"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="text-danger" ng-show="empList.emp_email.$invalid">Invalid Email!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
        <label for="" class="radio-inline gender">
            <input type="radio" name="emp_gender" ng-value="male_value" ng-model="empInfo.gender">Male
        </label>
        <label for="" class="radio-inline gender">
            <input type="radio" name="emp_gender" ng-value="female" ng-model="empInfo.gender" >Female
        </label>
    </div>

</form>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.male_value = 'male';
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hi5t1gU5TIdNx670wHo1?p=preview

Comment: What did i do wrong in my code ,please suggest my code

Comment: i did nothing in js  and cant we do this without js code?

Comment: please suggest with using radio buttons instead of buttons

Comment: @Krish look up now